# Assign vec to UInt ports

Tags: scala, hdl, chisel

if I have a io port which is io.myoutput = UInt(width = 840)

Then I have a val a = vec.fill(140){UInt(width = 6)}

How do i assign the entire a vec into the output port? I tried for loop with

```
for (i = 0 until 140){ 
io.myoutput(i*6+5,i*6) := a(i)}
```

But it gives me

```
finished inference (1)
start width checking
finished width checking
started flattenning
finished flattening (2)
Lbi.scala:37: error: reassignment to Node in class TutorialExamples.Lbi
Lbi.scala:37: error: reassignment to Node in class TutorialExamples.Lbi
Lbi.scala:37: error: reassignment to Node in class TutorialExamples.Lbi
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val x = Vec.fill(140){UInt(1, width=6)}
io.myoutput := x.toBits
```

The "toBits" method is what you want.  It flattens a Vec into its raw bits.

I'm not sure exactly what is causing the error message, but in general, you can't really reassign to specific bits in a wire in Chisel.

```
val y = Bits(0,width=32)
y(1) := UInt(0)
y(3) := UInt(3)
etc.
```

That will throw an error.

Comment: finished inference (4)
start width checking
finished width checking
started flattenning
finished flattening (941783)
resolving nodes to the components

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Now I am running into a problem that chisel compiler is too slow...resolving nodes to the components takes 4+hours to finish. And the generated verilog file has 1 million line.. Is that the nature of doing vec in chisel? It looks like chisel compiler only knows to use"assign" in verilog. It does not know how to optimized the code using "generate" in verilog

Comment: I don't know what your design looks like, so I can't accurately speak to whether 4+ hours is reasonable.

However, yes, Vec will typically generate a lot of nodes.  You should look at the generated Verilog to understand why (in short, a Vec has to describe in painful detail the read/write ports and the enable signals on each element in the Vec; whereas something like a Mem() structure provides a very fast .read() and .write() method (in the C++ backend anyways) to get in and out of the Mem. Of course, Mem only works if you want a Vec of Regs(), and you don't want to specify an initial value).

Comment: There are a couple of reasons your compile could be slow.  You might be hitting swap on your computer; perhaps you should give the java JVM more memory to work with; you might be using an older compiler which has poor performance compiling long functions (suggested that you be using gcc4.8).

If it's none of those issues, you might want to post your code to get feedback on it.

Comment: Show I will post the codes. I have tried different computers with different hardware and OS(Ubuntu, macOS). If I run it on small memory(2G on my macbook air) computer the jvM will give me out of memory error.